# Is there a way to execute a perl script from any location in the machine?

Tags: linux, perl

I'd like to know if there are other ways to execute a perl file without giving the path explicitly.

example:

```
perl ./images/seed/test.pl
```

I read on the export path command but I don't quite understand. Is that code supposed to be in the perl file? If so, please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: Probably you want to use a shebang on the perlscript, mark it as executable and place it on a directory that is included on the $PATH. Another alternative would be to use a bash alias

Comment: Once you set up the path, you'd use `test.pl` (or `perl -S test.pl`). The former requires the script to be marked as executable, and it must have a shebang (`#!`) line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP did not indicated what OS the script runs on.

OS: UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X

- add to top of the script `#!/usr/bin/env perl`
- or add to top of the script `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` (verify perl location with `which perl`)
- make the script executable `chmod u+x srcipt.pl` (or just `+x` to be executable by anyone)
- make *bin* directory for executables `mkdir ~/bin`
- move script to *bin* directory `mv scritp.pl ~/bin`
- add `~/bin` directory in login dot files (depends on used shell)
- check what shell you use `echo $SHELL`
- for example for **bash** edit **.bashrc** and add `export PATH $PATH:~/bin`
- logout/login to *pickup* made changes (or alternatively source ~/.bashrc)

At this point you should be able to start script at any location of filesystem.

OS Windows:

- Follow the [Instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727480/how-do-i-make-my-perl-scripts-act-like-normal-programs-on-windows)

Comment: Sorry there, I tagged the post as Linux but I should have typed it out in the question. Thank you for answering. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Execute in your shell the following command, to enable finding executable files in the directory `/path/to/perl/script`:

```
export PATH=/path/to/perl/script:${PATH}
```

If you plan to use the script in that path routinely, consider adding the above command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file.

Add to the Perl script this line as the very first line in the script (it tells the shell to use the Perl interpreter):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

Make the Perl script executable, so that you can execute it by typing its name:

```
chmod u+x /path/to/perl/script/perl_script_name.pl
```

Now you can execute the Perl script in any of the following equivalent ways:

```
perl_script_name.pl
# or:
/path/to/perl/script/perl_script_name.pl
# or:
perl /path/to/perl/script/perl_script_name.pl
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/13411)
[What should I use for a Perl script's shebang line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2791954/967621)

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for this. I'll try and understand commands. Really appreciate it.